# what is the best way to install Ansible from Terraform

Tags: ansible, terraform

Hi I am fairly new to the Ansible and Terraform world. We need to install Ansible from Terraform script. I have the script to install Ansible but want to know what is the best way to call that script from Terraform to make sure the script is called after the Virtual Machine is created. I have been reading about local-exec and remote-exec methods but they are not recommended by TF. Any help on the topic would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

From terraform yeah, you don't have much of a choice really.

The only way to do it is to use remote-exec provisioners as you said.

They are not recommended because terraform can't guarantee that they'll succeed. What I mean by this is, if the commands you give to provisioner fail, terraform will move on because it can't know the exit status of provisioners and commands you gave them.

What I would recommend you if you are able to and if that matches your use case is to use `packer`.

Packer is used for making images which later you use as a template for your instances. You configure your image by passing commands and/or scripts to the packer. That way you can run `sudo apt install ansible` or whatever the command is once in packer and from that point use that image wherever you need.